# Pointwise convergence of kernels of Hilbert-Schmidt operators

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, operator-theory

Lately I was discussing different types of convergence for Hilbert-Schmidt operators and during that discussion we ended up talking about pointwise convergence of Fourier series. I have already asked this question on mathstackexchange (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4271733/pointwise-a-e-divergence-sum-p-in-mathbbzd-c-pn-e2-pi-i-p-cdot-x) without much success. I hope this question is appropriate for mathoverflow, otherwise, please let me know.

We asked ourselves whether the following is true:

> Given a sequence of Hilbert-Schmidt operators $(T_N)_{N\geq 1}$ from $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ to itself such that the Hilbert-Schmidt norm is uniformly bounded and such that $(T_N)_{N\geq 1}$ converges in operator norm to a Hilbert-Schmidt operator $T$, is it true that the kernels $T_N(x,y)$ always admit a subsequence that converges almost everywhere to the kernel $T(x,y)$?

After some scribling on the blackboard we got quite convinced that this is false and we wanted to construct a counterexample. For this we considered the following type of operators.

Picking a Hilbert basis $(e_p)_p$ of $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$, we can consider operators of the type

$$ T_N = \sum_p c_p^{(N)} \vert e_p \rangle \langle e_p \vert, $$

with $c_p^{(N)}\in \mathbb{R}$. Then we have for the Hilbert-Schmidt norm, respectively the operator norm

$$ \Vert T_N \Vert_{HS} = \sum_p \vert c_p^{(N)} \vert^2, \quad \Vert T_N \Vert_{OP} \leq \sup_{p} \vert c_p^{(N)} \vert. $$

I thought, it might simplify our live, if we pick a specific Hilbert basis. Namely, we can pick $e_p(x) = e^{2\pi i \langle p, x\rangle} 1_{[0;1]^d}(x)$ and extend this to a Hilbert basis of $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$. So effectively, we can just look at function on the unit cube.

Thus, it would be enough to find an example ($x\in [0;1]^d$)
$$ f_N(x):=\sum_{p\in \mathbb{Z}^d} c_p^{(N)} e^{2\pi i \langle p, x \rangle}$$
where $\sum_{p} \vert c_p^{(N)}\vert^2<\infty$,
$$\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty}\sup_{p} \vert c_p^{(N)} \vert =0$$
and such that $(f_N)_{N\geq 1}$ diverges pointwise almost everywhere along all subsequenes. I am aware that pointwise convergence of Fourier series can be quite hard to deal with (Carleson-Hunt comes to my mind).

> What would be techniques to establish the existence of such an example?

My guess would be that it is difficult to exhibit an explicit example, but the mere existence should be much easier (maybe some type of Baire argument?).

If this is still too hard, I would already be happy if there was no subsequence such that $f_N$ converges pointwise a.e. to the zero function.